# Recover Magento checkout details where customer goes to Paypal and never returns

Tags: php, magento, paypal, checkout

When using Paypal Standard or Paypal Express, customers are directed to the Paypal website to either complete the sale, or sign in to their Paypal accounts to verify payment, respectively.  There is a significant percentage of customers who do not complete the sale from that point.

Magento reserves an Order Increment ID for these abandoned carts, and the `sales_flat_quote_address` table contains all the address details, however these don't appear in the Abandoned Carts report or anywhere else that I can see in the Admin.

It would be helpful to be able to display the order details as the customer has already entered contact information in the Shipping/Billing steps of the checkout, and hence should be open to being contacted to reactivate the checkout.

I'm looking for architectural suggestions on how to display these details and reduce the order leakage? Would a new Report be best, or a module that adds a node under the Sales menu.  I don't have any experience in writing new Reports, and the Sales Grid/Views are quite complex...

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize Abodoned Cart Report to display these carts. The collection method which is responsible for this report called `Mage_Reports_Model_Mysql4_Quote_Collection::prepareForAbandonedReport()` you just need to add `or`condition into this filter statement `$this->addFieldToFilter('main_table.is_active', '1')`. It filters only active shopping carts for now, that wasn't proceeded to "Place Order" step.  You need to include carts wich is not active and wasn't completed as full order.

Also you can create additional functionality for customer, when he is signing in, check for abandoned shopping carts, display some kind of notice with link for shopping cart restore. Then retrieve abandoned cart and set `is_active` attribute to `1`, so it will become an active shopping cart.

Hope it is a solution that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan. Those quotes are still showing `is_active = 1` at the moment.  The issue is that the `sales_flat_quote` table doesn't actually seem to track whether the `reserved_order_id` becomes an entry in `sales_flat_order`.  So I guess I need to extend the `prepareForAbandonedReport()` method with a join into the `sales_flat_order` table to find missing records.  I like the idea of checking for abandoned carts at login, but that will only work for customers who choose to register at checkout, not guests, right?

Comment: FYI, this query works, now I just need to convert it to a Zend_Db statement! `SELECT reserved_order_id FROM sales_flat_quote q LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order o on o.increment_id = q.reserved_order_id WHERE o.increment_id is null and q.reserved_order_id != ''`

Comment: @Jonathan, as for guest checkout, there is stored email in quote table, so you can create a cron script that will send email to guest checkout customers, for example with some unique random key. And when customer clicks on the link, your controller checks this key with list of abandoned carts and load matched cart as current.